# What is wrong with this C++ decimal to binary conversion code?

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, data-conversion

For some values (like 9) it works perfectly but, for most (like 7, 19 or 6), it subtracts 1 from the return (binary) value.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int decimaltobinary(int);
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<num<<" in decimal = "<<decimaltobinary(num)<<" in binary.";

    return 0;
}
int decimaltobinary(int num)
{
    int remainder,i=0,binary=0;
    while(num!=0)
    {
        remainder=num%2;
        num=num/2;
        binary=binary+remainder*pow(10,i);
        i++;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are confused about which language you are programming in.  The code is C++, but you have tagged the C language.  FYI, the C language doesn't have `std::cout` nor `std::cin`.  I recommend you updating your language tags.

Comment: `pow` works with floating point numbers, which are not exact. It may be introducing an off-by-one error you are seeing. If you start `i` at `1` you can multiply it by `10` instead of incrementing. Then you can use `i` instead of `pow(10,i)` which would only use integers.

Comment: Decimal and binary are **text** representations of values. Converting a value to its binary representation means converting it to text.

Comment: Instead of `pow(10, i)`, just accumulate the multiplier: `int i = 1;` before the loop, and in the loop do `binary = binary + i * remainder; i *= 10;`.

Comment: The program works fine for me (if num<1024 but that is because of the int overflows) Are you sure for 6 it outputed 101 for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with the shown code:

1. The shown code attempts to build a binary version of the input number ***in decimal*** producing, for example, the result of `111` for the number 7. That's an integer value of one hundred and eleven.

On a 32 bit platform, with a 32 bit integer means that the largest number that can be "converted" to decimal this way will be 2047. 2048 is 10000000000 in binary, which will exceed the capacity of a 32 bit integer. An unsigned 32 bit integer's maximum value is 4294967295 (and half of that for it's plain, signed, `int` value, but either signed or unsigned, you're out of gas at this point).

2. Any use of `pow()` with two values that are integets is automatically broken by default, becase [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/). This is not what `pow()` really does. Here's what `pow()` does: a) it takes the natural logarithm of its first parameter, b) multiples the result from step a by its 2nd parameter, c) raises `e` to the power resulting from step b. Does this sound like something you expected to do here?

And since `pow()` takes floating point parameters, and the result is a floating point, the end result of the shown code is a bunch of needless conversions between floating point and integer values, and non-specific rounding errors as a result of imprecise floating point exponential math.

But the main flaw in the shown code is an attempt to use plain `int`s to assemble a decimal number represented of a binary value, which simply doesn't have enough digits for this. Switching to `long long int` won't be much of a help. Counting things off on my fingers, you'll be able to go up only to somewhere slightly north of a million, that way. A completely different approach must be taken for the described programming tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `binary+remainder*pow(10,i);` is all done in floating-point arithmetic and only converted to `int` at the assignment. Since `pow` is not exact, you may get the result slightly below the exact value, in which case the conversion truncates it and makes 1 less than the desired result.

While there are various better ways to achieve your goal, the immediate fix is to use `std::round()` and then cast the result to int:

```
binary=binary+remainder*int(round(pow(10,i)));
```